Cypress opens link in new tab regardless removed/changed target
Cypress opens link in new tab, I already tried
cy.get("a[class='proof proofLink']").invoke('attr', 'target', '_self').click()

so as
cy.get("a[class='proof proofLink']").invoke('removeAttr', 'target').click()

and even though both methods do the work (removing and changing the target) after clicking on element link opens in new tab. I never had this problem in the past, both methodes worked quite good. Unfortunately I can't grab the link from the element by .then(link, ()=> cy.visit(link)) because there is no actual link in the element (I'm not sure how it works, I'm guessing it runs serious of actions after click so the link might be created). That's the element below:
<a href="" target="_blank" class="proof proofLink">
<div class="lefticon-icon icon-proof">
<span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
  <i class="fa fa-circle-thin fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-eye fa-stack-1x"></i>
</span>
</div>
</a>

I have tried with Cypress version 13.6.4 and 13.12.0, Bundled Node version: 18.17.1
EDIT:
I also tried this ChatGPT solution based on @CBroe answer :
cy.visit("my app")
cy.window().then((win) => {
  cy.stub(win, 'open').as('windowOpen');
});
pageObject.myMethod();

this piece of code goes after cy.visit("my app")
myMethod(){
      cy.get("a[class='proof proofLink']")
        .invoke('removeAttr', 'target')
        .click();
      // Optionally assert that window.open was not called
      cy.get('@windowOpen').should('not.have.been.called');
    }

Still doesn’t work, mi link opens in new tab.

Maybe there's a click handler attached, that explicitly calls window.open, with the target parameter hard-coded?

The empty href on the <a> element indicates that there is an event listener attached that is providing the target URL. The best course of action is to examine the code of the event handler, which requires the source code.
This example web page uses window.open() on the same <a> element you have (omitting the inner elements which aren't relevant).
<body>
  <a href="" target="_blank" class="proof proofLink">Open new window</a>
  <script>
    const a = document.querySelector('a')
    a.addEventListener('click', function open() {
      window.open('https://example.com')
    })
  </script>
</body>

The test uses onBeforeLoad event handler to set the stub, and assigns the stub to a variable so that the calls can be examined.
let stub, url;

cy.visit('/win-open.html', {
  onBeforeLoad: (contentWindow) => {
    stub = cy.stub(contentWindow, 'open').as('windowOpen')
  },
});

cy.get('a')
  .invoke('removeAttr', 'target')
  .click();

cy.get('@windowOpen')
  .should('have.been.called')
  .then(() => {
    const calls = stub.getCalls()
    url = calls[0].lastArg
    cy.visit(url)
  })


Strictly speaking the URL of the target page will be known to you, so you wouldn't need to get it from the call.
In a real test you would just visit that URL in a second test and continue testing from there, making sure to have test isolation switched on to provide good separation.
